# Python(Pygame) Key Error

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in pygame using a tilemap, and I've encountered the follwing error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Dusty\Dropbox\~MAIN FOLDER~\Projects\Sunless\game.py", line 52, in <module>
    surface.blit(textures[tileMap[row][column]], (column*tileSize, row*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize))
KeyError: 174"
```

With this code:

```
import pygame

gameIsRunning = True

tileSize = 32
mapHeight = 19
mapWidth = 25

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((tileSize * mapWidth, tileSize * mapHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

floor = 109
wall = 166

textures = {
            floor : pygame.image.load('data/floor.png'),
            wall: pygame.image.load('data/wall.png'),

            }

tileMap = [
           [109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109],
           [109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 166, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 166, 109, 109, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 166, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 109],
           [109, 109, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 109, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 109, 109, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109, 109, 174, 166, 166, 109],
           [109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 109, 109, 109, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 166, 166, 166, 109, 166, 109],
           [109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109]
            ]

def gameQuit():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
while gameIsRunning == True:
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for row in range(mapHeight):
        for column in range(mapWidth):
            surface.blit(textures[tileMap[row][column]], (column*tileSize, row*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameQuit()
```

Comment: What are `mapHeight` and `mapWidth`? And please show the __full__ traceback.

Comment: There's a `174` in your `tileMap`, a bit near the bottom right. What did you mean instead of that?

Comment: @Navith Ah I'm so stupid I can't believe I didn't catch that. It's suppose to be a 109 and I accidently placed a tile in Tiled other than the floor and wall. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small tip, if you want to make a game using tilemap use [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/), also use [TMX import library by Richard Jones](https://bitbucket.org/r1chardj0n3s/pygame-tutorial/src/995c364f087cc24e20682f642b3b406e7e3dcdae/tmx.py).

Also it appears you are trying to access element that isn't in textures. You have value 174 in `tileMap` (3rd row from end).

```
surface.blit(textures[tileMap[row][column]]
```

Right here you access element that doesn't exist in textures dictionary. It's interpretted as:

```
textures[174]
```

And since there is no such key in textures you have the error.